# help with resolving a mathematical induction exercise

Tags: linear-algebra, induction

The text of the problem is

> Prove that for every $n\geq 1$ (belonging to the set of natural numbers) the following equality is true:
> $$1^6+2^6+3^6+\dots+n^6 = n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^4+6n^3-3n+1)/42$$

This is what I've been able to do so far:

I have verified that it is true if $n = 1$.

I have supposed that it is true for $n$ belonging to $\mathbb{N}$ and then tried verifying that
$$1^6+2^6 +3^6+...+n^6+(n+1)^6 = (n+1)(n+2)(2n+3)[3(n+1)^4+6(n+1)^3-3n-2)/42$$

I'm going to indicate the right part of the equation with an $(\ast)$ and try to rewrite it, therefore:
\begin{align}
(\ast) & = (n+1)(n+2)(2n+3)[3n^4+18n^3+36n^2+27n+7)/42 \\
& = (n+1)(2n+3)(3n^5+24n^4+72n^3+99n^2+61n+14)/42 \\
& = (n+1)(6n^6+48n^5+144n^4+198n^3+122n+28)/42 \\
& = (n+1)(6n^6+6n^5-66n^4-222n^3-88n-14) + (n+1)^6
\end{align}
I don't know how to continue at this point so that I can obtain
$$[n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^4+6n^3-3n+1)/42] + (n+1)^6$$

Comment: I've taken the liberty of typing up the math expressions using MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: @ElliotYu thank you so much, I was actually looking for this information :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in mutliplying by $(2n+3)$: you should get $$6n^6+57n^5+216n^4+414n^3+419n^2+211n+42$$ (I think you forgot to multiply by 3).

Comment: if anyone knows any faster way to resolve these kinds of equations please let me know